# Mysql View Working Method?

Tags: mysql

How the Mysql View is working **Internally** ?

```
create view testView  as select * from employee;
```

if run this what will happen **internally**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, crating a view doesn't really do much until it is called on.  It pretty much just gets validated until it is used.

Views usually use the `MERGE` method which merges the query for the view with the query that calls it.  The other method for views is `TEMP TABLE` which creates a temporary table whenever it is needed, but this is less common.

An basic example of a view using the `MERGE` method:

View Query:

```
SELECT t1.col1, t2.col2, t2.col3 FROM t1 JOIN t2 USING(id) WHERE x = 1
```

Calling Query:

```
SELECT col1, col3 FROM view WHERE y = 2
```

MySQL basically executes this query as:

```
SELECT col1, col3 FROM (SELECT t1.col1, t2.col2, t2.col3 FROM t1 JOIN t2 USING(id) WHERE x = 1) WHERE y = 2
```

However, since the queries get merged and optimized, it would be optimized to a simpler form like this:

```
SELECT col1, col3 FROM t1 JOIN t2 USING(id) WHERE x = 1 AND y = 2
```